# How do I format a Double with two decimal places?

Tags: java, format, double, decimal

I'm trying to display a `Double` to two decimal places (like `0.00`). I don't want to use `system.out.print` as the value must appear in a `textArea`. I am currently getting

> £ 2.5

instead of

> £ 2.50

My code looks sort of like this:

```
DecimalFormat myDecimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
String text = myDecimalFormat.format(total);
```